# conditional probability Pc(B)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

I am looking for the probability of Pc(B) where the event of B={no two people are born in the same month} and event C= {exactly three people were born in the summer of june, july august} and there are 9 people involved.

for

```
P(B) i got =1/12 * 1/11 * 1/10 * 1/9 * 1/8 * 1/7 * 1/6 * 1/5 * 1/4 =1/79833600
P(C)=(9 choose 3)((3/12)^3)((9/12)^6)=(15309/65536)
so 
Pc(B)=P(C|B)=P(B intersection C)/P(C) = (P(B)*P(C))/P(C)
=((1/79833600) * (15309/65536))/(15309/65536)
```

Is my logic correct? if not where did i go wrong

Comment: Why do you think $P(B) =(\frac{1}{12})^9=1/5159780352$?

Comment: oh sorry wrong events, give me a second to fix that.

Comment: okay fixed... i think

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to say that totaly 9 borns should be ocoured.

Comment: yes sorry, added that in the question

Answer (score 0):

Detailed: You have nine borns which exactly three of them are in the summer. This means you can not have all states of event $B$ with $C$(some of them will be ineligible). So they aren't independent. Now we have:
$$P(B \cap C) = (\frac{3\times2\times1}{12^3})(\frac{9\times8\times\ldots4}{12^6})$$
$$P(C) = (\frac{3}{12})^3(\frac{9}{12})^6$$
$$P(C|B)=\frac{P(B \cap C)}{P(C)}$$
Previous pervious answer was wrong:
Your events aren't independent. So $P(B \cap C) \ne P(B)*P(C)$. For instead you have $P(B \cap C) = (\frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1})(\frac{1}{9}\frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{4})$

Comment: I don't really see how you obtained those numbers. But i understand that because they aren't independents P(B intersection C)!= P(B) * P(C). Because P(B intersection C)=P(B)*P(C) only applies if they are independent. But please explain the formula for P(B intersection C) when B and C is not independent.

Comment: I found the formula: P(B intersection C)=P(C|B)*P(C) can you explain it? Also if P(C)=1/3 * 1/2 * 1/1 i don't think that is correct with 9 people. P(C)=(9 choose 3)((3/12)^3)((9/12)^6)=(15309/65536)

would i do something like: P(C|B)=(P(C)P(B|C))/P(B)?

Comment: Also how do you tell if they are independents or not? From looking at the events i guess you can tell but isn't there the formula that if P(A|B)=(P(A)*P(B))/P(B)   = P(A) then it is independent? =((1/79833600) * (15309/65536))/(15309/65536) = (1/79833600) which is P(A)